# Calling a getter method from a parent abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, struts, abstract-class

This is how my classes look like:

```
public abstract class BaseForm extends Z{
    protected String someString;

    public String getSomeString(){
        return this.someString;
    }

    public void setSomeString(String some){
        this.someString = some;
    }
}
```

---

```
public abstract class AdvancedForm extends BaseForm{
    protected Something selectedThing;
    protected List<Something> listOfThings;

    public Something getSelectedThing(){
        return this.selectedThing;
    }

    public void setSelectedThing(Something thing){
        this.selectedThing = thing;
    }    

    public List<Something> getListOfThings(){
        return this.listOfThings;
    }

    public void setListOfThings(List<Something> list){
        this.listOfThings = list;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class FinalForm extends AdvancedForm{
    //Lot of stuff done here
}
```

So I have something similar to what you can see above. The problem comes when I create a JSP and it tries to call the `get/setListOfThings` methods.

```
<html:html>
    ...
    <html:select name="FinalForm" property="selectedThing">
        <html:optionsCollection name="FinalForm" property="listOfThings" label="label" value="value" />
    </html:select>
    ...
</html:html>
```

I know I'm missing something here (`struts-config.xml` and `tiles-def.xml` exist and are correct), but my point of view is that struts should be calling the `FinalForm`'s `setListOfThings` method. And this should be calling the `AdvancedForm`'s `setListOfThings` method (which is the one implemented) because `FinalForm` is extending `AdvancedForm` and I'm not overriding the method in the `FinalForm`.

Anyhow, this is not working and I don't know what's wrong. The only way it works is if I override the method and call explicitly the `setListOfThings` from the `AdvancedForm`.

```
public class FinalForm extends AdvancedForm{
    //...
    public List<Something> getListOfThings(){
        return super.getListOfThings();
    }
}
```

I want to avoid that overriding because the point of creating the `AdvancedForm` class is to remove a lot of functionality that most of my forms are using (but not all of them, this is the reason for the existence of `BaseForm` and `AdvanceForm` classes).

Any ideas why this is not working? Any ideas to improve this? Anyone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your function will definitely work great. But if you are rendering the result in struts json it will not get super class properties.
If it is json you have to define your struts.xml in following way

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
</result>
```

Similar discussion: [How to include parent class fields in json response using struts 2 json plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083363/how-to-include-parent-class-fields-in-json-response-using-struts-2-json-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the method `public` instead of `protected` in the superclass, otherwise the Struts classes won't be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's my mistake, the getters and setters are all public, I'm going to edit the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not working only because the method is protected. Once you override it, it works because you make the overriding method public.

Just make the base methods public and (almost) everything will be OK.

Once the form is submitted, the `setSelectedThing` method should be called. The problem is that Struts is not able to magically transform the `String` parameter it receives in the request into a `Something` instance. Your getter and setter for the `selectedThing` property should use `String` rather than `Something`.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote protected instead of public in the methods. They already are public (getters and setters). Do I have to do the same with the variables?

Comment: I've edited my answer. The variables should be private. Struts and the JSP EL only access properties via their getter and setter.

Comment: I tried to change everything in the AdvancedForm to public but it does not work. The only way it works is if I create the getters and setters in the FinalForm and this methods call the super methods.