# How to include parent class fields in json response using struts 2 json plugin

Tags: json, struts2

I have following implementation

```
public abstract class BaseAcion extends ActionSupport {
    private String result;
    private String message;

    //getters, setters
}

public class MyAction extends BaseAction {
    private String myFirstField;
    private String mySecondField;

    public String execute() {
         ...
         myFirstField = "someValue";
         mySecondField = "someOtherValue";
         ...
         result = SUCCESS;
         message = "Some message here";
         ...
         return result;
    }

    //methods, getters, setters
}
```

I have used struts2-json plugin, action mapping is

```
<package name="my-package" namespace="/" extends="json-default" >
    <action name="myAction" class="MyAction">
        <result type="json"></result>
    </action> 
</package>
```

The response that I receive is something like this.

```
{
    "myFirstField":"someValue",
    "mySecondField":"someOtherValue"
}
```

I want to get "result" and "message" fields in response as well.

How can I include BaseAction fields in json response?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default properties defined on base classes of the "root" object won't be serialized, to serialize properties in all base classes (up to Object) set "ignoreHierarchy" to false in the JSON result:

Something like

```
<result type="json">
  <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
</result>
```

For details refer to the JSON plugin documentation

- [JSONPlugin-BaseClasses](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html#JSONPlugin-BaseClasses)

Comment: thank you. But It will serialize all properties of parent. I just want two property of parent in json. I guess I have to use "excludeProperties" in each action mapping. Is there any cleaner way ?

Comment: yes that's the way to exclude them else create an inner class within your Action that contains just the information you want to include in the JSON and set it as the base/root object to marshal.

Comment: Instead of creating inner class in each action, I think it's better to extend JSON Result Type in my own way. I am going to dive into json plugin. Thanks Umesh for your valuable solution and ideas.

Comment: You can even create an inner class in your base action and use that as root object or can use reg expression for including/excluding properties